# Why can't we contact a specific address range from inside our LAN?

Tags: iptables, routing, connection, networking

We can't connect to a specific external server from inside our LAN.

However we can connect to the same server from outside our LAN, at home, or using a mobile phone.  It was working just fine for months, and one day it stopped working. I can't figure out what, if anything, changed when it stopped working.

I'm trying to develop a procedure to troubleshoot this and pinpoint the problem.

The server is a hosted CentOS vps.  If I ping any of it's 3 IP addresses from inside our LAN, the ping times out.  If I try to connect to web servers on the vps, it times out.  If I perform a tracert, I get these results:

```
Tracing route to static-161-150-73-69.nocdirect.com [69.73.150.161] over a maximum of 30 hops:

1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
3    34 ms    10 ms    30 ms  96.120.4.229 
4    10 ms    12 ms     8 ms  xe-11-1-0-32767-sur01.n4atlanta.ga.atlanta.comcast.net [68.85.68.61] 
5     9 ms    15 ms    12 ms  xe-9-0-2-0-ar01.b0atlanta.ga.atlanta.comcast.net [68.86.106.182] 
6    14 ms    23 ms    23 ms  he-5-12-0-0-10-cr01.56marietta.ga.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.93.125] 
7    16 ms    15 ms    15 ms  pos-0-1-0-0-pe01.56marietta.ga.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.86.86] 
8    21 ms    12 ms    16 ms  173.167.57.134 
9     *       19 ms    18 ms  ae3-20g.cr2.atl1.us.nlayer.net [69.31.135.165] 
10    18 ms    13 ms    16 ms  as46562.ae6-1677.cr2.atl1.us.nlayer.net [198.47.120.146] 
11    11 ms    16 ms    25 ms  184.170.245.254 
12    13 ms    21 ms    15 ms  209.140.17.58 
13    23 ms    12 ms    19 ms  arya.nocdirect.com [69.73.150.66] 
14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
17     *    [10.0.0.144]  reports: Destination host unreachable.
Trace complete.
```

Our LAN is behind a D-link DFL-800 firewall.  I can't see any rules on the firewall to block traffic to these 3 addresses.

I CAN ping other IP addresses that are probably at the hosting company, IP's that are slightly above and below the IP range.

Here's a successful tracert from outside our LAN

```
Tracing route to static-161-150-73-69.nocdirect.com [69.73.150.161] over a maximum of 30 hops:

1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.1 
2    28 ms    22 ms    26 ms  c-76-111-52-1.hsd1.ga.comcast.net [76.111.52.1] 
3     9 ms     8 ms    10 ms  xe-11-0-0-32767-sur01.b6powsprings.ga.atlanta.comcast.net [68.85.68.109] 
4    53 ms    17 ms    13 ms  xe-11-1-1-0-ar01.b0atlanta.ga.atlanta.comcast.net [68.85.108.169] 
5    19 ms    23 ms    23 ms  he-5-13-0-0-10-cr01.56marietta.ga.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.93.201] 
6    12 ms    15 ms    12 ms  pos-0-11-0-0-pe01.56marietta.ga.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.88.186] 
7    13 ms    16 ms    18 ms  173.167.57.134 
8    11 ms    17 ms    10 ms  ae0-50g.cr1.atl1.us.nlayer.net [69.31.135.129] 
9    13 ms    13 ms    10 ms  ae1-40g.cr2.atl1.us.nlayer.net [69.31.135.138] 
10    12 ms    12 ms    11 ms  as46562.ae6-1677.cr2.atl1.us.nlayer.net [198.47.120.146] 
11    18 ms    70 ms    23 ms  184.170.245.254 
12    12 ms    16 ms    16 ms  209.140.17.58 
13    13 ms    13 ms    11 ms  arya.nocdirect.com [69.73.150.66] 
14    15 ms    20 ms    13 ms  static-161-150-73-69.nocdirect.com [69.73.150.161] 
Trace complete.
```

## Resolution:

I SSH'd into the server and followed the procedure outlined in the following blog post.

[How to Remove and Add Rules to IP Tables Chains in Centos Linux](http://blog.cnizz.com/2010/10/12/how-to-remove-and-add-rules-to-ip-tables-chains-in-centos-linux/)

1 Dump all the rules to a file

> iptables -L -n --line-numbers > /tmp/ip.tables

2 Edit the file using [vi](http://www.howtogeek.com/102468/a-beginners-guide-to-editing-text-files-with-vi/)

> vi /tmp/ip.tables

3 Locate LOCALINPUT or LOCALOUTPUT rules that DROP your IP.  Make a note of the rule number.

4 Delete the rules

> iptables -D LOCALINPUT {rule#}
>
> iptables -D LOCALOUTPUT {rule#}

5 Add rules to allow your IP

> iptables -A INPUT -p all -s {IP} -j ACCEPT
>
> iptables -A OUTPUT -p all -s {IP} -j ACCEPT

Comment: Get up on that server and look at its firewall entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the firewall entries on the remote server. Most likely something is blocking ICMP requests used by ping and traceroute.

Comment: Iptables had a rule that blocked connections from our primary IP Address.  The server uses cPanel and WHM, we're thinking someone from our office tried to log in and got the password wrong too many times, and it auto-created a block rule.  We removed the rule and added a new set to allow connections from our IP.